# Fetching names from core data and converting it to upper case

Tags: core-data, xcode4.5

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"salesRepName == %@",salesName];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
This is my fetching.  Is it possible to fetch the name from table and directly converting to UPPER CASE without using a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. The only way (as far as I know) to fetch computed results in a Core Data fetch request is using `NSExpressionDescription` with `[NSExpression expressionForFunction:…]`,
and that does not support the `uppercaseString` function. So you have to convert the values
to uppercase after fetching them.

Answer (score 0):

`NSExpression` does support `uppercase:` like below:

`NSExpression(forFunction: "uppercase:", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "name")]`

I've used it with `NSBatchUpdateRequest` successfully like below to convert all names to uppercase without fetching the records:

```
let batchUpdateRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "Person")
batchUpdateRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

// Convert name to uppercase
batchUpdateRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["name": NSExpression(forFunction: "uppercase:", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "name")])]

batchUpdateRequest.resultType = .UpdatedObjectIDsResultType
try! self.context.executeRequest(batchUpdateRequest)
```